# using windows 7 sound effects

Tags: c#

how to use windows 7 messagebox sound effect and animating form in creating  custom messagebox using C#

thank you

Comment: Hello, this is a bit vague. What do you mean by animating form? Are you using Windows Forms or WPF (or possibly, are you unsure what to use)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

The feature you probably need is "Windows Vista and Windows 7 Task Dialogs".