# play windows 7 sound effect in C#

Tags: c#

hi
I want to play a windows 7 sound effect when a user clicks a button in my Windows windows application in XP using C#

thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to play a Windows 7 sound effect in Windows Xp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using windows 7 sound effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873399/using-windows-7-sound-effects)

Comment: which sound effect?   Why not just include the audio file in the application?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .NET Framework class [`System.Media.SystemSounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsound.aspx).

[From the C# FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/03/27/562557.aspx):

> To play for example the classical beep sound, you could use the following code:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

> Similarly, you could play the “Question” sound with this code:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Question.Play();
```

For the **Windows 7 and XP issue**, you'd have to import the .wav files from 7 into XP, and associate those .wav to the appropriate events.

Alternatively, you could embed any .wav file into your application as a resource, and play it from your app. Likely easiest is the [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

In button click you can call this

```
 using System.Media;
 Protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\Windows7.wav");
    simpleSound.Play();
 }
```

Note: If you are looking for .wav for windows. normally it is present in the folder

**C:\Windows\Media...**